# Want to know the differences between exponential and heavy-tailed distributions in terms of first and third quartiles

Tags: distributions, quantiles, exponential-distribution, heavy-tailed

What are the differences between exponential and heavy-tailed distributions, please illustrate this difference by explaining how well the first and 3rd quartiles describe them.

I know  what are exponential and heavy-tailed distributions, but I don't know how to explain the difference in terms of first and third quartiles. Any help is much appreciated. thanks,

Comment: Since both "exponential distribution" ([def. 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution); [def 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)) and "heavy-tailed distributions" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution) gives three definitions) have multiple different definitions, please tell us what you know them to be.

Answer (score 2):

A heavy-tailed distribution on the other hand has a heavier tail, in the sense that the probability of observing a large value x is proportional x-a, where a is a positive integer. Exponential
distributions are reasonably well described by the first and third quartile as their deviation
around the mean is limited, and these quartiles will likely capture most of the mass of the
distribution. Heavy-tailed distributions on the other hand will be described best by high
quantiles, e.g., the percentile 95 or 99, so the first and third quartile will not sample the
large values of a heavy-tailed distribution.